# Texmacs Ubuntu 18.04.03 and Python

Tags: ubuntu, bash, python, latex

I am trying to install TeXmacs for Ubuntu, but it is not available via apt-get. The instructions on the site tells us to download a zip and run it through a bash script (https://www.texmacs.org/tmweb/download/unix.en.html_. The problem is that TeXmacs cannot find a python plug-in, even though i have the latest python version in my system. I also have installed from synaptic some other python packages but that didn't solve it.

Also when i run the bash-script,

```
export TEXMACS_PATH=/home/captain/Apps/TeXmacs/TeXmacs-1.99.11-x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/TeXmacs
export PATH=$TEXMACS_PATH/bin:$PA
texmacs &
```

TeXmacs starts and terminal shows this:

```
TeXmacs] sh: 1: which: not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured it out and the problem was the PATH variable was overwritten with this script.
I changed

```
export PATH=$TEXMACS_PATH/bin:$PA
```

to

```
export PATH=$PATH:$TEXMACS_PATH/bin:$PA
```

and everything worked fine.